# OPENMP Parallel Problem Error for Double Loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I was getting the error: "free(): corrupted unsorted chunks" when trying to run:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:save) shared(save2)
   for (size_t i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
    vector<float> dist = cdist(i, arestas);
    vector<float> distinv(dist.size());

    for (size_t j = 0; j < N(); ++j) {
      if (arr[j] > 0)
        arrv[j] = (1/N) + (1 / arr[j]);
      else
        arrv[j] = 0;
    }
    save = accumulate(arrv.begin(), arrv.end(), 0.0);
    vector<double>::iterator iter = save2.begin() + i;
    save2.insert(iter, sum);
  }
```

Comment: When you say, "the code isn't working," what do you mean?  What happens?  What output do you get?

Comment: free(): corrupted unsorted chunks

Answer (score 2):

I might miss the point here, but what about just doing it this way (not tested)?

```
vector<double> sum2(N);

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    double sum = 0;
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < dist.size(); ++j ) {
        if ( dist[j] > 0 ) {
            sum += 1. / dist[j];
        }
    }
    sum2[i] = sum;
}
```

There is still some room for improving this version (by removing the `if` statement for example, in order to help the vectorization), but unless you had some unexplained constrains in your code, I think this version is a good starting point.